# NX + Nest Js + Mongoose :- Class.name is not working with nx monorepo style import. but works with absolute path

Tags: angular, mongoose, nestjs, nrwl-nx, nestjs-mongoose

I am trying to implement an application using nestJs using nx monorepo concept.
I ran into one issue which is a bit strange, I can't figure it out how this is happening like this..

I have a organisation schema which is registered in organisation Module, I also have an auth module with userschema and products module productschema registered..

Recently I changed the data model to have mongo db collection for organisation to have embedded products and embedded users.

this change made it mandatory that I have to import the schemas defined in the products and auth to be imported into the organisation module as the org schema no will have products and users as subdocuments

```
import { User, UserSchema } from '@jafar-tech/backend/auth';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Product, ProductSchema } from '@jafar-tech/backend/products';

import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema()
export class Organisation extends Document {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
  @Prop()
  caption: string;
  @Prop()
  type: string[];
  @Prop()
  address: string;
  @Prop()
  coord: string[];

  @Prop()
  license: string;

  @Prop({ default: true })
  openAllWeek: boolean;

  @Prop()
  offDays: string[];

  @Prop({ type: [ProductSchema], default: [] })
  product: Product[];

  @Prop({ type: [UserSchema], default: [] })
  users: User[];
}

export const OrganisationSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Organisation);
```

If I keep this schema like this. I get this error for this line of code..

code:

```
   @Injectable()
export class ProductsRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Organisation.name) orgModel: Model<Organisation>,
    @InjectModel(Product.name)
    private readonly product: Model<Product>
  ) {
```

Organisation.name is the culprit..this is the error.

```
/home/jafar/nx/jafar-tech/dist/apps/table-qr-api/webpack:/jafar-tech/libs/backend/products/src/lib/products.repository.ts:10
    @InjectModel(Organisation.name) orgModel: Model<Organisation>,
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at Object../libs/backend/products/src/lib/products.repository.ts (/home/jafar/nx/jafar-tech/dist/apps/table-qr-api/webpack:/jafar-tech/libs/backend/products/src/lib/products.repository.ts:10:31)
```

Strange thing I have the same dependency injection for organisation.name in the auth module but that doesn't show this error.

The real question is : When I try to make the productSchema import as the absolute without @nx/nrwl way of importing with tsconfig path map. It seems to work with no error.

```
import { User, UserSchema } from '@jafar-tech/backend/auth';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import {
  Product,
  ProductSchema,
} from 'libs/backend/products/src/lib/models/product.schema';

import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema()
export class Organisation extends Document {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
  @Prop()
  caption: string;
  @Prop()
  type: string[];
  @Prop()
  address: string;
  @Prop()
  coord: string[];
```

look at the above organisation schema.. Here when I import the product and product schema using the absolute path. It works with no error.

Questions:

1. Any idea why absolute path works and not the @ import.
2. If you look at the auth module import in the schema which is @ import and which also has the organisation.name injected into one of its repository, but that works well without the absolute path.??

I am stuck at this problem.. plz help